# Issue with negative lookbehind in R

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this set of sentences:

```
w <- c("so i said er well it would n't surprise me if it could bloody talk",  # quote marker
        "we got fifteen, well thirteen minutes",                              
        "well she brought a pie and she brought some er punch round",         
        "so your dad said well have n't i been soft ?",                       # quote marker
        "And he went [pause] well I can't feel any. ",                        # quote marker
        "I goes well they'll improve the grant to start off with",            # quote marker
        "so with the chips as well this is about one sixty .",                
        "well we 're not all the same are we , but")
```

All strings contain the word `well`. I'm interested in those strings where `well` acts as a quote marker, as indicated by the occurrence of `said`, `goes`, and `went`. Using **positive** lookbehind I can match these sentences:

```
grep("(?<=said|goes|went).*well", w, value = T, perl = T)
[1] "so i said er well it would n't surprise me if it could bloody talk"
[2] "so your dad said well have n't i been soft ?"                      
[3] "And he went [pause] well I can't feel any. "                       
[4] "I goes well they'll improve the grant to start off with"
```

The issue I have is that **negative** lookbehind to match those string in which 'well' is **not** a quote marker does *not* work. For example, this matches everything:

```
grep("(?<!said|goes|went).*well", w, value = T, perl = T)
[1] "so i said er well it would n't surprise me if it could bloody talk" # not match
[2] "we got fifteen, well thirteen minutes"                              # match
[3] "well she brought a pie and she brought some er punch round"         # match    
[4] "so your dad said well have n't i been soft ?"                       # not match         
[5] "And he went [pause] well I can't feel any. "                        # not match             
[6] "I goes well they'll improve the grant to start off with"            # not match         
[7] "so with the chips as well this is about one sixty ."                # match      
[8] "well we 're not all the same are we , but"                          # match
```

Why doesn't it match correctly and how would it have to be changed to match correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't you just want to invert your matches in the positive look-behind? `grep(..., invert = TRUE)`

Comment: I'm familiar with that option but in the post I was specifically intererested in digging a little deeper into negative lookbehind. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because `(?<!said|goes|went)` matches a location in the string that is not **immediately** preceded with the strings defined in the lookbehind. `.*` then matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `well` is matched. There are a lot of such valid positions.

The easiest is to match those strings where `said`, `goes` or `went` occur before `well` and skip them, then match `well` in all other contexts:

```
\b(?:said|goes|went)\b.*\bwell\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\bwell\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zh1kLd/1).

**Caution**: If you use a solution like `^(?!.*\b(?:said|goes|went)\b).*\bwell\b`, you may get false negatives when `said`, `goes` or `went` appear *after* `well`.

**Pattern details**

- `\b(?:said|goes|went)\b.*\bwell\b(*SKIP)(*F)` - a whole word: `said`, `goes` or `went` and then any 0 or more chars as many as possible and then a whole word `well`, after this match is found, it is dropped and the regex engine starts looking for a match at the current failed position
- `|` - or
- `\bwell\b` - a whole word `well`.

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/bw62w4):

```
grep("\\b(?:said|goes|went)\\b.*\\bwell\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\\bwell\\b", w, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "we got fifteen, well thirteen minutes"                     
# [2] "well she brought a pie and she brought some er punch round"
# [3] "so with the chips as well this is about one sixty ."       
# [4] "well we 're not all the same are we , but"
```